# How to convert generic dictionary to non-generic without enumerating?

Tags: .net, collections

I want to convert an instance of generic [`IDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) to non generic [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx). Can I do it without creating new instance of `IDictionary`? Is any framework support for this task?

I tried wrapping the generic `IDictionary<,>` in a class that implements nongenetic `IDictionary` however I discovered that I then have to also somehow convert generic `ICollection<>` to nongeneric one so I went with Mark Gravell's solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It all depends on the *concrete* implementation you are using.

For example, Dictionary<TKey,TValue> implements both the generic IDictionary<TKey,TValue> and the non-generic IDictionary - so if you have a Dictionary<TKey,TValue> you can use it as either without issue:

```
        Dictionary<int, string> lookup = new Dictionary<int,string>();
        IDictionary<int,string> typed = lookup;
        IDictionary untyped = lookup;
```

However, this doesn't necessarily apply for all IDictionary<TKey,TValue> imlpementations, since it is not true that IDictionary<TKey,TValue> : IDictionary. If you are deep in the bowels of some generic code, you could test the current dictionary:

```
        IDictionary<int,string> typed  = ...
        IDictionary untyped = typed as IDictionary;
        if(untyped == null) {/* create by enumeration */}
```